# Why does LINK.EXE need a .EXP file to accommodate circular dependencies among .DLL files?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, linker, shared-libraries

**NOTE:** All cases of `.LIB` refer to `link.exe` import libraries, rather than archives of object files.

I've spent a long time figuring out how one accommodates circular dependencies among `.DLL` files in Windows. It's because I'm working with a `makefile` that is having unresolved externals amongst circularly dependent shared libraries. I figured that I needed to understand more about the linker...

I'm going to recap a little, just because it's quite easy to forget. Not only this, but there's a high chance that there are issues in my understanding of linking in Windows. Any corrections would be helpful.

For the sake of this question, I have 3 files: *exec.obj*, *one.obj*, and *two.obj*.

**Scenario:**

1. *`one.obj`* contains a symbol defined in *`two.obj`* and is linked by `link.exe` into a `.DLL`.
2. *`two.obj`* contains a symbol defined in *one.obj* and is linked by `link.exe` into another `.DLL`.
3. *`exec.obj`* contains symbols defined in both *`one.obj`* and *`two.obj`* and is linked by `link.exe` into an `.EXE`.

**A common circular dependency problem:**

When `one.obj` is processed by `link.exe`, `one.dll` and `one.lib` (its import library) are created. The purpose of `one.lib` is to describe the exported symbols found within `one.dll`.

At this current point in time, `one.dll` cannot import symbols from `two.obj` because `two.obj` hasn't been processed by `link.exe` and so `two.lib` (import library) doesn't exist yet. Because of this, `one.dll` contains unresolved references to symbols defined in `two.obj`.

Just like `one.obj`, when `two.obj` is processed by `link.exe`, it creates an import library (`two.lib`) and `two.dll`. However, `two.obj` can actually find it's own unresolved references by looking inside `one.lib`. At this point, `one.dll` has unresolved references, and `two.dll` doesn't. Either way, `exec.obj` will have unresolved references when processed.

**A common circular dependency solution:**

The problem is that whenever you try to link `one.obj` into a `.DLL`, it searches for unresolved references, turns `one.obj` into a .DLL and creates a corresponding `one.lib` (import library) all in the same step. Once the step is complete, it's too late to search for any other unresolved references because `one.obj` is now `one.dll`.

The solution would be breaking down the steps. Creating the corresponding import library (`one.lib`) without turning `one.obj` into `one.dll`. This would allow `one.obj` to be processed by `link.exe` at a later time, thus not disabling it's ability to use `two.lib` when `two.obj` is eventually linked.

**The question:**

When creating the corresponding import library (`one.lib`) in its own single step using `link.exe`, another file called `one.exp` is created. I don't see why it's necessary. If `one.obj` still exists, it can find it's unresolved references in `two.lib` when `two.obj` is processed. However, from what I've read, it's necessary to include `one.exp` in the final step. **Instead of just processing `one.obj` and having it find `two.lib`, `one.exp` also has to be added to the list of files fed into `link.exe`. Why?** `two.lib` already describes the symbols needed by `one.obj` and `two.exp` was never needed to process `two.obj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewind the clock to the late 1980s, back when exports were specified with the linker's `/DEF` or `/EXPORT` options.  They make the second link step to produce `one.dll` brittle, you'll shoot your leg off when you don't use the *exact* same options.  [Avoided by linking `one.exp`, and omitting the options, it is now no longer possible to get them wrong and the linker won't rewrite `one.lib`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/dot-exp-files-as-linker-input)

Not very relevant anymore, almost everybody uses the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute today to specify exports.  I don't see an obvious failure scenario when you don't link `one.exp` in that case, other than having the `one.lib` filedate newer than `two.dll` and causing to be rebuilt unnecessarily.  Not so sure, I never once got myself into a pickle like this.

Comment: So essentially, a .EXP file is just there to make the process easier? It's not actually necessary though if you can be bothered copying out the exact same /EXPORT options? I use the __declspec(dllexport) attribute so apparently the .EXP file is pretty much useless because my exports are already defined in the .OBJ file itself? Haven't had the time to test because I'm busy with some other tasks.

Comment: No idea how you got "easier", it makes it more reliable.  No idea why you'd consider reliability something to avoid.  Just do it.

Comment: Well it just helps me narrow down what could be the problem in my makefile. It seems like the .EXP file isn't part of it.